# Does Rails/ActiveRecord access the DB if you save a model without changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I find myself doing the following when saving a model might be costly (maybe because I'm saving a ton of them):

```
changed = false
if user.name_changed?
  #do some stuff
  changed = true
end
if user.birthdate_changed?
  #do some other stuff
  changed = true
end
user.save! if changed
```

Is the use of `changed` unnecessary? Will `user.save!` automatically do nothing if nothing has been changed?

Using Rails v3.2.16, but happy to upgrade to 4.0 if it works better in this regard.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need the variable `changed`, you can generally just check `if user.changed?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord's `save!` method will **always** access the database. So yes, your `changed?` method appears to be necessary.

See [the documentation on ActiveRecord.save!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save!).

Comment: The documentation makes no mention of whether `save` or `save!` accesses the database if no changes were made.

Comment: It says, "If the model is new a record gets created in the database, otherwise the existing record gets updated." The key words, "the existing record _gets updated._" Try it out in the rails console, and you'll see that a query is executed when you run `save!`.